# Setting XIB inside custom cell tableView issue

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, xib

I have followed this this tutorial

[How to visualize reusable xibs in storyboards using IBDesignable](https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-visualize-reusable-xibs-in-storyboards-using-ibdesignable-c0488c7f525d)

I have added a label inside the view to change the label and I'm calling the xib inside the custom cell for tableView. So I'm facing this issue,

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

While I’ve added this code inside the view and linked it

```
@IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
```

This is how I'm calling it inside the custom cell.

TableViewcell code:

```
class ProductListBigTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productQuantity: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productAddButton: BaseButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var prodcutPriceView: PriceView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        productFirstName.text = "first product"
        productFirstQuantity.text = "4 p"
        prodcutPriceView.priceLabel.text = ""
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

I can figure that the view is not initialised yet so it is nil. I could not find a way or resource how to change a value inside XIB inside the UITableViewCell. So how I can change it and initial the view for the XIB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: @NazmulHasan I have updated my question.

Comment: did linked correct way `@IBOutlet weak var itemNameLabel: UILabel` with xib

Comment: @NazmulHasan updated.

Comment: @NazmulHasan Could you help me with it?

Comment: create a sample project something like this and share anywhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149729/discussion-between-nazmul-hasan-and-can).

Comment: did you guys figure out the solution?